# Move to next curly brace in Sublime Text 3

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, curly-braces

Is there a way to jump to the next curly brace? I am aware of CTRL+M for Mac, but that only jumps to the **matching** brace. I would like to jump to the **next** brace, as I find using the arrow keys to do this a pain. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on why you want to jump to another bracket, you could accomplish in at least three ways.

- use <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, select far left icon (use regex) and then search for `\{|\}`. Just continue to press return to jump between each instance.
- write a macro which uses `move` and a regex
- You might benefit by using the [EasyMotion](https://github.com/tednaleid/sublime-EasyMotion) package.

> EasyMotion is a Sublime Text 2 plugin that allows you to move the
>   cursor to any character in your current view.
>
> It's heavily inspired by Vim's EasyMotion, and Emacs' AceJump plugins.
>
> After pressing the EasyMotion shortcut (default cmd-;/ctrl-;), you
>   then press the character that you'd like to jump to. EasyMotion will
>   then replace all currently visible instances of that character with
>   one of a-zA-Z0-9. Press the key for the one you want and your cursor
>   will be moved right to it.

For example, if you have something like the following:
[image]

and you are interested in moving through all of the `{` characters, then you can press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>,<kbd>{</kbd> and it will hightlight all of the `{`'s present, and label them, starting with `a`.

[image]

Press the letter that corresponds with the `{` you want to move to, in this case I pressed `d`. (Screenshot caught the blinking cursor while 'off', but you can see where the underscore is present).

[image]